# Structured data

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hello I am working on the data structure. I have following problems:

1. when I dump ($ data), I have all the info.
2. I am looking for how has integrated a php variable in json.
   here is my piece of code. I have serious problem with concatenation. thank you in advance

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
     {
      "name":"<?php ($data[restaurant_name]);?>"
      "author": {
        "@type": "<?php.....?>",
        "name": "<?php.....?>"
      },
      "datePublished": "<?php ($data[date]);?>",
      "description": "<?php ($data[description]);?>",
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't concatenate into JS. Construct an object/array in PHP then use `json_encode`

Comment: @CertainPerformance you should write an answer instead of comment, do it so I can upvote (and OP can accept it)

Comment: I 100% agree with the frst comment. However, for the future, if you want to output a value in a variable, you need to [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [print](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) them at some point. Just writing the variable on it's own doesn't actually do anything at all. Also, array keys should be quoted: `$data['date']` instead of `$data[date]`. The PHP parser will fix that for you at runtime, but it will also throw a warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not construct JSON objects like this, it's error-prone!

just using PHP construct an associative array, then use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to create valid JSON object and pass whole to JS.

```php
// variables
$name = 'Foo';
$type = 'bar';
$authorName = 'John';

// array
$data = [
    'name'   => $name,
    'author' => [
        '@type' => $type,
        'name'  => $authorName
    ]
];

// encode to JSON and display
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: am i just using php? no need to put the <script> tag and is google going to understand that?
Thanks for your help

Comment: We do not know what exactly you need. What we're trying to each you is that you NEED to build JSON string like I showed you instead of *manual* glueing. That way you don't need to care about special characters, missing brackets, etc. if it's required just wrap it finally with `<script ...>` tag, this function returns just a string